# Numpy.shape tuple - order of elements

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand how the tuple returned from numpy.shape is structured. My understanding was that for the 3 dimensional ndarray the tuple is (`number of matrices`, `number of rows in each`, `number of columns`)

For a 3d ndarray like this

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

   [[ 7, 86,  6, 98],
    [ 5,  1,  0,  4]],

   [[ 5, 36, 32, 48],
    [97,  0, 27, 18]]])
```

that is indeed how it works. The shape is (3, 2, 4) ie. three dimensions, each with 2 rows and 4 columns.

The problem is, I have an ndarray from `scipy.misc.face()` (the racoon image) and when I check the img.shape it returns `(768, 1024, 3)`. So this should mean that there are 768 dimensions, each with 1024 rows and 3 columns. But that is not the case. The `img.ndim` returns 3 , which means there are only 3 dimensions. So why isn't the returned tuple (3, 768, 1024)?

Comment: The 3 normally is the color dimension of an image.  Often it is last, but can be first.  Depends on what the image display package expects.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So this should mean that there are 768 dimensions.

No it means that there are 768 values in third dimension. i.e. 768 matrices of shape 1024x3. The first value in the tuple represents the outermost dimension, the last value in the tuple represents the innermost dimension.

Shape `(768, 1024, 3)` means that there are 768 matrices of the shape `1024x3`, and shape `(3, 768, 1024)` means that there are 3 matrices of shape `768x1024`

The example you have,

```py
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

   [[ 7, 86,  6, 98],
    [ 5,  1,  0,  4]],

   [[ 5, 36, 32, 48],
    [97,  0, 27, 18]]])
```

There are 3 records for the outermost dimension, two records for the first inner dimension i.e. rows, and 4 records for the innermost dimension i.e. columns,
Hence, the shape is (3,2,4).

Comment: Thanks, it seems I was confusing "dimensions" with "matrices". This clears it up nicely

Comment: @NoncomissionedRush, Great